# Tensorflow 2.1.0 Error, module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphKeys'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just installed new tf and cuda today, but when I run the previous code that worked with tf-1.4 won't work under new tensorflow-2.1.0 and cuda-10.1

How to fix this?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yea, I change the import as `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf` and the error is gone. May I know how did you find this change, as it might be challenging to look it up into the documentation for migrate?

Comment: I googled the title of your question and looked at the top 10 google hits.  It's perfectly OK to answer your own question if you like. Especially since you are the one that tested it and know it works.

Comment: here is the search, the migrate documentation is #7 in the list: https://www.google.com/search?q=Tensorflow+2.1.0+Error,+module+%27tensorflow%27+has+no+attribute+%27GraphKeys%27&rlz=1C1NHXL_enUS828US828&filter=0&biw=1322&bih=616

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you Robert. I opened it once actually when I did the search, then I saw the the migrate, but I am so noob that didn't feel it's the case lmao.

Answer (score 3):

Mentioning the Solution in the Answer Section (even though it is present in Comments Section), for the benefit of the Community.

Replacing the command,

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

with

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

has resolved the error.

For more information about Migrating from Tensorflow 1.x to 2.x, please refer this [Tensorflow Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) and this [Upgrade Script](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade) also will be helpful.