# Install cleverHans on windows

Tags: python, machine-learning, cleverhans

I hope all of you are doing Great.
I need to install cleverhans on windows for some project but once installed it was unable to access any python file in there and I got a lot of errors like:

```
<ipython-input-12-4fbd91cef426> in <module>
     10 import numpy as np
     11 
---> 12 from cleverhans.attacks import FastGradientMethod
     13 from cleverhans.compat import flags
     14 from cleverhans.dataset import MNIST

~\src\cleverhans\cleverhans\attacks\__init__.py in <module>
     10 
     11 from cleverhans import utils
---> 12 from cleverhans.attacks.attack import Attack
     13 from cleverhans.attacks.basic_iterative_method import BasicIterativeMethod
     14 from cleverhans.attacks.carlini_wagner_l2 import CarliniWagnerL2

~\src\cleverhans\cleverhans\attacks\attack.py in <module>
     11 
     12 from cleverhans.compat import reduce_max
---> 13 from cleverhans.model import Model
     14 from cleverhans import utils
     15 

~\src\cleverhans\cleverhans\model.py in <module>
      7 import tensorflow as tf
      8 
----> 9 from cleverhans import utils_tf
     10 
     11 

~\src\cleverhans\cleverhans\utils_tf.py in <module>
    343 
    344 def kl_with_logits(p_logits, q_logits, scope=None,
--> 345                    loss_collection=tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES):
    346   """Helper function to compute kl-divergence KL(p || q)
    347   """

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphKeys'
```

I hope to have a lot of answers from you.
Have a nice day.

Comment: is tensorflow installed correctly? maybe the attributes/classes of that module has changed through the verions? I would check the requirements or at least the release date of cleverhans. (have never heard about that).

Comment: Yes TensorFlow is installed and it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cleverhans is designed to use an older version of tensorflow. To make it downward compatible replace

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

with

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

in the cleverhans source code or look if there is an updated version of cleverhans available or uninstall tensorflow and install an older version (v1) instead.

See:
[Tensorflow 2.1.0 Error, module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphKeys'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890090/tensorflow-2-1-0-error-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-graphkeys)

From cleverhans GitHub repo:

"**Currently supported setups**

Although CleverHans is likely to work on many other machine configurations, we currently test it it with Python 3.5 and TensorFlow {1.8, 1.12} on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (Trusty Tahr)."

Comment: Has this worked for anyone?
seriously, what should the tf version be for cleverhans??